# How to build a list of growing initials of a string with itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a Python string:`"d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"`

I want to split it into:

`["d4", "d4 d5", "d4 d5 c4", ... , "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"]`

I'm not sure how to run `itertools` on it.

Comment: That isn't "splitting" it, because the pieces overlap. Try to break the problem down into logical steps: if you *do* split it into each move (do you know how to do that?), can you think of a way to create the first value you want? The second? Generalize that for the nth? Iterate that to get all the results?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this with `itertools`. In Haskell, this function would be called `inits`, but I see no equivalent in Python. That being said, it would be pretty easy (especially with generators and `yield`) to write it yourself in Python.

Comment: What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Why `itertools` specifically? If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask]. (Maybe this comment is moot now that you've gotten answers, but I mention it at least for future reference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need itertools at all.

Try:

```
s="d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"

li=s.split()

>>> [' '.join(li[0:i]) for i in range(1,len(li)+1)]
['d4', 'd4 d5', 'd4 d5 c4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4']
```

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) used in a plain manner is *almost* what you want:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> s = "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"
>>> list(accumulate(s.split()))
['d4',
 'd4d5',
 'd4d5c4',
 'd4d5c4e6',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf4',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf40-0',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf40-0e3',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf40-0e3Nbd7',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf40-0e3Nbd7g4',
 'd4d5c4e6Nc3Be7Nf3Nf6Bg5h6Bf40-0e3Nbd7g4dxc4']
```

If you want the spaces in there, you'll need a custom accumulator function to add the spaces, e.g.:

```
>>> list(accumulate(s.split(), '{} {}'.format))
['d4',
 'd4 d5',
 'd4 d5 c4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
list(map(' '.join, accumulate(zip(s.split()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an `itertools` problem. In Haskell, the function is called [`inits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits), but Python doesn't have an equivalent built-in. We can write it ourselves.

```
def inits(xs):
    yield ()
    acc = []
    for x in xs:
        acc.append(x)
        yield tuple(acc)
```

Note that we return newly-constructed tuples so as not to share any data between iterations. We also yield the empty tuple *first*, since it's a valid prefix of a list. If you don't want that in your output, you can filter out the first element.

Now it's just a bit of fixing up the data with `join` and `split`.

```
my_string = "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"
my_moves = my_string.split(" ")
my_prefixes = map(" ".join, inits(my_moves))
print(list(my_prefixes))
```

Comment: `accumulate(zip(xs), initial=())` would be be equivalent to your `inits(xs)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here one using list comprehension, regular expressions (`from re import re.finditer as r` ) and slicing (`s` is the string to process). This way all the splitting and joining again is not necessary:

```
[s[0:m.start()] for m in r(" ",s)]+[s]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `regex`:

```
import regex

s = "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"
regex.findall(r"(?<=(?: |^)(.*)(?: |$))", s)

['d4',
 'd4 d5',
 'd4 d5 c4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4',
 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4']
```