# Timing of function changes after changing its position in script

Tags: python, timing

I have written a Python script to compare performance of different solutions to a question asked [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808350/how-to-build-a-list-of-ordered-strings-with-itertools) ( How to build a list of growing initials of a string with itertools? ).

What I am wondering about is that the resulting timing of a function seem to depend on the position in code in relation to the other functions. I have attached both versions of the script I am running with examples of output. The issue is not always 100% reproducible, but at least at 90% of the runs.

In the position as last in the script the timing seem to be always above 7.0

```
inits_lstcm_slice_regex # Claudio       :  7.1699229
```

where placing the function as first in the script the timing improve and is mostly below 7.0:

```
inits_lstcm_slice_regex # Claudio       :  6.7658726
```

How does it come? Can you reproduce the behavior I am speaking about? What is the reason for this strange outcome and how can I fix the code to produce more reliable timing comparisons and make the relative timing not dependent on the position at which a function is placed in the code?

Below the two versions of the same script with one of the functions at the begin and at the end of the section with functions:

```
def get_root_defs(filename):
    with open(filename) as f: 
        Lines = f.readlines()
    Fs = []
    for i, line in enumerate(Lines):
        if line.startswith('def inits_'):
            Fs.append( (line[4:line.index('(')], Lines[i+1][4:Lines[i+1].index('(')-1]) )
    return Fs
Fs = get_root_defs(__file__)
# print(f'{Fs=}')

from itertools import accumulate
def inits_lsmap_accum_zipsp(sep, s):
    # Kelly Bundy ( list(map())->lsmap, accumulate->accum, ), zip split->zipsp
    return list(map(sep.join, accumulate(zip(s.split(sep)))))

from itertools import accumulate
def inits_laccu_split_formt(sep, s):
    # ShadowRanger ( list(accumulate())->laccu, split, formt->format )
    return list(accumulate(s.split(sep), '{} {}'.format))

def inits_lstcm_sjoin_slice(sep, s): 
    #  dawg ( list comprehension->lstcm, slice, split )
    li = s.split(sep)
    return [sep.join(li[0:i]) for i in range(1,len(li)+1) ]

def inits_haskl_gener_fnctn(sep, s):
    # Silvio Mayolo ( haskel generator function->haskl_gener_fnctn )
    def inits(sep, LsplitS):
        # yield ()
        acc = []
        for e in LsplitS:
            acc.append(e)
            yield tuple(acc)
    return list(map(sep.join, inits(sep, s.split(sep))))
# ========================================================
import numpy as np
def inits_lstcp_numpy_slice(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    I = np.nonzero(np.array([*s])==' ')[0].tolist() 
    return [ s[0:i] for i in I ] + [s]

def inits_tryex_gener_fnctn(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    def get_i(sep, s):
        i,j = (0,0)
        while True:
            try:
                j = s[i:].index(sep)
                i += j
                yield i
                i += 1
            except ValueError:
                yield len(s)
                break
    return [ s[0:i] for i in get_i(sep, s) ]

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_slice(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    return [ s[0:i] for i in [ i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i] == sep ] ] + [s]

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_step2(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    i = 1
    len_s = len(s)
    I = []
    #sT = T()
    while i < len_s:
        # if s[i].startswith(sep):
        if s[i] == sep[0]:
            I += [i] # .append(i)           
            i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    #eT = T(); print(f'while i < len_s : {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    #sT = T()
    S = [s]*(len(I)+1)
    #eT = T(); print(f'S=[s]*(len(I)+1): {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    #sT = T()
    for i, v in enumerate(I): 
        S[i] = S[i][0:v]
    #return [ s[0:i] for i in I ] + [s]
    #eT = T(); print(f'for i,v in enum(: {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    return S

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_enumr(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    return [ s[0:i] for i in [ j for j, c in enumerate(s) if c == sep ] ] + [s]

from re import finditer as r
def inits_lstcm_slice_regex(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( regex, slice, lstcm->list comprehension )
    return [s[0:m.start()] for m in r(sep,s)]+[s] 


# I have a Python string:
s0 = "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"
s1 = 600 * s0
sep = " "
# I want to split it into:
L = ['d4', 'd4 d5', 'd4 d5 c4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4']

from time import perf_counter as T
tf = 100
for defName in Fs:
    if defName[0].startswith('inits'): 
    #if defName[0].startswith('inits') and defName[1].startswith('# Claudio'):
        assert eval(f"{defName[0]}(sep, s0)"), f'{defName}' == L
        exec(f"sT=T();{defName[0]}(sep, s1);eT=T();print(f'{defName[0]} {defName[1].ljust(15)} : "+"{tf*(eT-sT):10.7f}')" )

output = """
inits_lsmap_accum_zipsp # Kelly Bundy   : 87.7965652
inits_laccu_split_formt # ShadowRanger  :  7.3266540
inits_lstcm_sjoin_slice #  dawg         : 88.3612148
inits_haskl_gener_fnctn # Silvio Mayolo : 88.2759180
inits_lstcp_numpy_slice # Claudio       :  7.8032393
inits_tryex_gener_fnctn # Claudio       :  8.2205204
inits_chrlp_lstcp_slice # Claudio       :  7.3996746
inits_chrlp_lstcp_step2 # Claudio       :  7.5269613
inits_chrlp_lstcp_enumr # Claudio       :  7.4681612
inits_lstcm_slice_regex # Claudio       :  7.1699229
"""
```

```
def get_root_defs(filename):
    with open(filename) as f: 
        Lines = f.readlines()
    Fs = []
    for i, line in enumerate(Lines):
        if line.startswith('def inits_'):
            Fs.append( (line[4:line.index('(')], Lines[i+1][4:Lines[i+1].index('(')-1]) )
    return Fs
Fs = get_root_defs(__file__)
# print(f'{Fs=}')

from re import finditer as r
def inits_lstcm_slice_regex(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( regex, slice, lstcm->list comprehension )
    return [s[0:m.start()] for m in r(sep,s)]+[s] 

from itertools import accumulate
def inits_lsmap_accum_zipsp(sep, s):
    # Kelly Bundy ( list(map())->lsmap, accumulate->accum, ), zip split->zipsp
    return list(map(sep.join, accumulate(zip(s.split(sep)))))

from itertools import accumulate
def inits_laccu_split_formt(sep, s):
    # ShadowRanger ( list(accumulate())->laccu, split, formt->format )
    return list(accumulate(s.split(sep), '{} {}'.format))

def inits_lstcm_sjoin_slice(sep, s): 
    #  dawg ( list comprehension->lstcm, slice, split )
    li = s.split(sep)
    return [sep.join(li[0:i]) for i in range(1,len(li)+1) ]

def inits_haskl_gener_fnctn(sep, s):
    # Silvio Mayolo ( haskel generator function->haskl_gener_fnctn )
    def inits(sep, LsplitS):
        # yield ()
        acc = []
        for e in LsplitS:
            acc.append(e)
            yield tuple(acc)
    return list(map(sep.join, inits(sep, s.split(sep))))
# ========================================================
import numpy as np
def inits_lstcp_numpy_slice(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    I = np.nonzero(np.array([*s])==' ')[0].tolist() 
    return [ s[0:i] for i in I ] + [s]

def inits_tryex_gener_fnctn(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    def get_i(sep, s):
        i,j = (0,0)
        while True:
            try:
                j = s[i:].index(sep)
                i += j
                yield i
                i += 1
            except ValueError:
                yield len(s)
                break
    return [ s[0:i] for i in get_i(sep, s) ]

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_slice(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    return [ s[0:i] for i in [ i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i] == sep ] ] + [s]

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_step2(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    i = 1
    len_s = len(s)
    I = []
    #sT = T()
    while i < len_s:
        # if s[i].startswith(sep):
        if s[i] == sep[0]:
            I += [i] # .append(i)           
            i += 2
        else:
            i += 1
    #eT = T(); print(f'while i < len_s : {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    #sT = T()
    S = [s]*(len(I)+1)
    #eT = T(); print(f'S=[s]*(len(I)+1): {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    #sT = T()
    for i, v in enumerate(I): 
        S[i] = S[i][0:v]
    #return [ s[0:i] for i in I ] + [s]
    #eT = T(); print(f'for i,v in enum(: {eT-sT:10.7f}')
    return S

def inits_chrlp_lstcp_enumr(sep, s):
    # Claudio ( )
    return [ s[0:i] for i in [ j for j, c in enumerate(s) if c == sep ] ] + [s]


# I have a Python string:
s0 = "d4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4"
s1 = 600 * s0
sep = " "
# I want to split it into:
L = ['d4', 'd4 d5', 'd4 d5 c4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4', 'd4 d5 c4 e6 Nc3 Be7 Nf3 Nf6 Bg5 h6 Bf4 0-0 e3 Nbd7 g4 dxc4']

from time import perf_counter as T
tf = 100
for defName in Fs:
    if defName[0].startswith('inits'): 
    #if defName[0].startswith('inits') and defName[1].startswith('# Claudio'):
        assert eval(f"{defName[0]}(sep, s0)"), f'{defName}' == L
        exec(f"sT=T();{defName[0]}(sep, s1);eT=T();print(f'{defName[0]} {defName[1].ljust(15)} : "+"{tf*(eT-sT):10.7f}')" )

output = """
inits_lstcm_slice_regex # Claudio       :  6.7658726
inits_lsmap_accum_zipsp # Kelly Bundy   : 86.7529857
inits_laccu_split_formt # ShadowRanger  :  7.7288590
inits_lstcm_sjoin_slice #  dawg         : 87.9976579
inits_haskl_gener_fnctn # Silvio Mayolo : 88.7987813
inits_lstcp_numpy_slice # Claudio       :  7.7087794
inits_tryex_gener_fnctn # Claudio       :  8.3114856
inits_chrlp_lstcp_slice # Claudio       :  7.2907403
inits_chrlp_lstcp_step2 # Claudio       :  7.4924239
inits_chrlp_lstcp_enumr # Claudio       :  7.2369144
"""
```

Comment: As an aside: You can get at the functions themselves from `globals()`, so you don't need to "parse" the file itself in `get_root_defs` to get a list of names, or mess with eval and exec either.

Comment: The physical ordering of the functions doesn't matter; the run order evidently does (so I suspect there might be some JIT/specialization going on). https://gist.github.com/akx/e2010d49fe64e8c012605f791affd4a5 In the .txt file (which is a bit messy maybe), you can see that when run alphabetically, the first iterations are always a bit slower than the following ones.

Comment: What do you mean with *the first iterations are always a bit slower than the following ones*? The often observed issue that the first iteration runs from the source code file (which change time is fresher han that of the byte-code if byte-code is available) and the next iterations are using the in the first iteration created byte-code saving time on compilation? ( P.S. I need to parse the functions from source code in order to get more information about them as only their name and the pointer - e.g. the name of the poster on stackoverflow)

Comment: What is the evidence for *The physical ordering of the functions doesn't matter; the run order evidently does*? Have you tested that either changing the position of the functions in the source code along with changing the order of running of the functions?

Comment: No, I mean that within each `hyperfine` execution, all functions are run 5 subsequent times (try ctrl+f for "inits_chrlp_lstcp_enumr" on the gist page to highlight where the repeats are) and you can see the first sequence of 7 tests is significantly longer than the rest. With the next invocation of the program (line 36 and so on), it's again slower for the first cycle.

Comment: Bytecode compilation is absolutely negligible in this case anyway, and no .pyc files are saved _in any case_ since this is not an import but a direct script run (see the `hyperfine` command lines). (P.S. You wouldn't need to do that if you had written the metadata in a machine-readable form, e.g. a decorator, or in the docstring.) The evidence is that you can see the `hyperfine` command lines, and that the script isn't physically changed on disk, and yet the times are very different w/ `alpha` and `lineno`. With `lineno`, the previously observed first-cycle slowdown doesn't occur.

Comment: The total timing +- intervals overlap a bit, so statistically there is a chance that the results are not really different and what we observe is just randomness, but ... randomness doesn't explain the observed bias, so it seems that there must be other reasons for the observed behavior. In other words: fine tuning the code based on timings seem eventually not to be a very good idea.